# Variable range of the loop in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder, lstm

I implemented the code for LSTM in tensorflow and each of my batch has different length. In order to feed the data to the graph I need to have variable length list of inputs.

I would like the below loop to have a variable range in tensorflow. I can initialize it to a specific value at the start when graph is created but then any modification is not possible. I tried to use the length of the global list as external parameter but it did not work.

```
self._train_data = []
for _ in range( variable_length ):
    placeholder_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[self._batch_size, self._input_size])    
    self._train_data.append(placeholder_input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TensorFlow seq2seq tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html) discusses the problems with variable lengths and includes code to deal with them. It was written before tf.while_loop, which now allows you to deal with multiple lengths even better. But the general rules still apply, so take a look there!

Comment: I created the code for lstm cell and I would like to use it. In order to extend it I would like to add variable sequence size / variable number of unrollings. How can I use tf.while_loop in this case? I can use it to execute the code placed in the question and append only certain numbers of placeholders to the list, however the feeding process is done before this loop and an error occurs that "list index is out of range"